# didSelectAnnotationView not called

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotationview

I would like to work with an annotation once it's clicked. I've looked it up on the documentation of Apple and I did googled but I can not find why this is any different than how it should be done.
Basically; I don't get a `println("Pin clicked");`

Why not?

```
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView!
{
    if !(annotation is MKPointAnnotation) {

        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "test"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        anView.canShowCallout = true

    }
    else {
        anView.annotation = annotation
    }

    return anView
}
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!)
{
    println("Pin clicked");
}
func setAnnotationPinOnMap(annotation : NSManagedObject)
{

    var subject: AnyObject? = annotation.valueForKey("subject")
    var desc: AnyObject? = annotation.valueForKey("desc")
    var langitude: AnyObject? = annotation.valueForKey("langitude")
    var longitude: AnyObject? = annotation.valueForKey("longitude")
    println(annotation);
    let pin = MKPointAnnotation()

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: longitude as CLLocationDegrees,
        longitude: langitude as CLLocationDegrees
    )
    println(location.longitude, location.latitude)
    pin.setCoordinate(location)
    pin.title = subject as String!
    pin.subtitle = desc as String!
    println( pin.coordinate.longitude)
    viewForAnnotation(pin);
    mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
}
```

I have imported map kit and included the map view delegate.

Comment: Is the map view's `delegate` property set?  If not, the delegate method won't get called.  Also make sure the annotation's `title` (which is set to `subject`) is not blank or nil.

Comment: Two unrelated things: 1) When setting `location`, latitude is set to longitude and longitude is set to langitude which seems backwards.  2) The viewForAnnotation function as written is pointless.  It returns a view but the code does nothing with it and **it's not named correctly as the map view's delegate method**.  It must be named `func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView!` and the map view's `delegate` must be set.  You're not supposed to call it directly.

Comment: I did not set the map View's delegate I think. I now set it to : mapView.delegate = self. Now, no pins are shown (formerly pins did show, just not with the click event thrown)

Comment: Do you have the mapView(mapView:viewForAnnotation:) method implemented?  If you do, comment it out and see if the pins show.

Comment: If I comment the mapView viewforannotation function it shows the pins. I updated the main post with the current version of viewforannotation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer the original question, `didSelectAnnotationView` was most likely not getting called because the map view's `delegate` property was not set.  Another common cause is if the annotation's `title` is blank.

In the updated question, the pins won't show with the way `viewForAnnotation` is implemented because it creates an `MKAnnotationView` but doesn't set its `image` property.  The `image` property of an `MKAnnotationView` is `nil` by default so the pins are there but invisible.

If you want to display standard red pins, either:

- Don't implement the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method at all and the map view will display red pins *by default*.
- Implement the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method and create an `MKPinAnnotationView` instead which automatically displays a "pin" image.

So either set the pin's `image` to some custom image:

```
anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
anView.canShowCallout = true
anView.image = UIImage(named:"CustomImage")  // <-- add this line
```

or create an `MKPinAnnotationView` instead and optionally set its `pinColor`:

```
var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
if anView == nil {
    anView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    anView!.canShowCallout = true
    anView!.animatesDrop = true
    anView!.pinColor = .Purple  // or Red or Green
}
else {
    anView!.annotation = annotation
}
```

Comment: Hi Anna, thank you very much for such a great answer. My problem (as correctly pointed out by you) was that I didn't set a title for the view. What if I don't want to set a title? Is there any other option?

Comment: Vlad, did you find an answer to your question? I would also want to make a custom view which has a label in it. The problem is that if I set the title it appears in my View, but also on the right, next to my custom view

Comment: The blank title fixed it for me. More specifically, I had accidentally deleted the "- (NSString *)title;" declaration from my .h file.

Answer (score 7):

In my case the problem was that i was setting the property **canShowCallout** in YES, so if you set this property in YES

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

isn't called. when i removed this property the method was called.

```
annotationView = [[ClusterAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
annotationView.canShowCallout = YES; //try setting to NO or don't set.
```

Comment: `canShowCallout = false`
for Swift solved it for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add this as a comment to GOrozco58 answer but do not have enough reputation to comment.

**GOrozco58** is right if you have **canShowCallout** set to YES the `didSelectAnnotation` will not be called if the title is nil.

If you want `didSelectAnnotation` to be called and also have **canShowCallout** set to YES make sure you add a title.

Comment: then lets get you some rep!

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version of Swift, the method declaration has changed from this:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!)
```

to this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using costume annotation and the didSelectAnnotationView was not being called because of the image property for the custome annotation was empty, so I set it to image and the didSelectAnnotationView started to be called.

```
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        DoctorCustomeAnnotation *mapItem = (DoctorCustomeAnnotation *)self.annotation;

        // offset the annotation so it won't obscure the actual lat/long location
        self.centerOffset = CGPointMake(100, 100.0);
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        PAImageView* avatarView = [[PAImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)
                                             backgroundProgressColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                                                       progressColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.092 green:0.383 blue:0.580 alpha:1.000]];
        [self addSubview:avatarView];
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder_male"];
        [avatarView setImageURL:@"http://www.straine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/doctor.png"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anna's suggestion of the annotation's title not being assigned was the resolution for my problem. It took me a minute to implement this and I did that in gestureRecognizer() function. Here is my example:

```
    @objc func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state != .began { return }
    print("Tap gesture recognized")

    // Create the annotation
    let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: mapView)
    let newCoordinate = self.mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom:self.mapView)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate
    annotation.title = "placeholder"

    // Add the annotation
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```